# Create a basic loop in React

Tags: reactjs

I got React noob question.. The thing is that I have great number of fuctions that is almost indentical except that the method name and the properites is the differences between this two code blocks.

In my example, the first method is named xxx and the next yyy. The properties are named aaa and bbb.

To the question, how can I loop this in a smart way so I don't need a bunch of almost identical methods? I want to have only one method.

```
xxxx(blogItemNum: number) {
    return (
        this.state.dataLoadedLeadershipBlogDataItems ? (
            this.state.leadershipBlogDataItems.length > blogItemNum ?
                <aaaa item={this.state.leadershipBlogDataItems[blogItemNum]} index={blogItemNum} labels={this.props.labels} /> : ""
        )
            : ""
    );
}


yyyy(blogItemNum: number) {
    return (
        this.state.dataLoadedLeadershipBlogDataItems ? (
            this.state.leadershipBlogDataItems.length > blogItemNum ?
                <bbbb item={this.state.leadershipBlogDataItems[blogItemNum]} index={blogItemNum} labels={this.props.labels} /> : ""
        )
            : ""
    );
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need such a method in the first place. Why do you have to pass the index as a parameter and you don't look over `dataLoadedLeadershipBlogDataItems` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, don't do the index check in the method at all, pass `item` and `index` directly into the function:

```
xxxx(item, index: number) {
  return (
    <aaaa item={item} index={index} labels={this.props.labels} />
  );
}
```

That is, just move the common code out of the method to another shared place.

Also, if you are looping correctly over `this.state.leadershipBlogDataItems`, you won't actually need `this.state.leadershipBlogDataItems.length > blogItemNum` checks.